# ubuntu server not seeing ethernet port

Tags: networking, server, internet, ethernet

i am trying to setup ubuntu server on a normal desktop computer. the install went fine (even though it didnt connect to the internet) i figured i would have to change some network config settings. but i cant find anything wrong with the file.

```
auto eth0
iface etho inet6 dhcp
```

no attempt to connect works. any ideas?

i would think it would have something to do with it not being mounted or morthing of that nature. a kind of secondary question is, if everythin in linux is a file, where do i see all of the hardware? and would that be a good place to start looking?

Comment: In your snipset, you have etho instead of eth0 on the second line. Maybe a mistyping in the question, or this is the problem ?

Comment: Oh no. I mistyped. I'm sorry

Comment: So, you mistyped in the question, or in your real /etc/network/interfaces? If it's in the question, and your problem is not solved, what does 'ip link' give you ? I have seen some onboard network interfaces called p2p1 instead of eth0.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem myself.

Sources [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html) [and here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uifconfi.htm)

In your installation did it say "Network autoconfiguration failed
Your network is probably not using the DHCP protocol. Alternatively,
the DHCP server may be slow or some network hardware is not working
properly."

In the terminal try:

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

it will give you a list of hardware and should give you an output that looks something like this:

```
*- network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:15:c5:4a:16:5a
       size: 10MB/s
       capacity: 100MB/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: (snipped for brevity)
       configuration: (snipped for brevity)
       resources: irq:17 memory:ef9fe000-ef9fffff
```

If you return nothing your hardware may be faulty.

If your network is disabled try one of these three commands too bring it up:

your logistical name will be listed in your first output.

1. `ip link set dev <logistical name> up`
2. `/sbin/ifconfig <logistical name> up`
3. `ifconfig <logistical name> up`